# How do you identify what series a Pokemon card is from?

Tags: pokemon

Just from looking at the Pokemon card, is it possible to determine what series the card is from e.g. Hidden Fates, Steam Siege etc.? The copyright states the year but not which release quarter the card is from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each card contains a logo indicating which set it is from.  This image was taken from [here](https://www.professor-oak.com/Guide.asp).  A list of all the set logos is available [here](https://www.professor-oak.com/TradingCards/Default.php).   I know link only answers are discouraged but there are many of these and can easily be googled.

[image: pokemon card image]

Comment: Perfect! Still need a table but that clears things up enormously

Comment: There is a link to table in answer.  I felt it was to many to paste here

Answer (score 0):

**In difference to [@StartPlayer's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/51245/22542) all the cards I own have expansion icon in lower left corner as can be seen on the the card detail shown below.**

Instead of having expansion list, you could use Pokémon TCG Card Dex official application:

1. [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pokemon.marvelous&hl=sk&gl=US)
2. [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pok%C3%A9mon-tcg-card-dex/id1448310257)

There you can search your card and see name of expansion on card detail:
[image: Pikachu card detail with expansion written - Hidden Fates]

You can also use this application as a list of expansions and just compare expansion icon.

[image: List of expansions]